# How to Compare Date and set Button to set another background resources

Tags: android, date, compare

I have two dates in String and I compare them like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy");

Date date1 = formatter.parse(final_date.toString());
Log.e("Taggal Selected:",date1.toString());

String str2 = "March 10, 2017";
Date date2 = formatter.parse(str2);

if (date1.compareTo(date2)<0)
{
   btn_lunch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lunch_inactive);
   btn_dinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dinner_inactive);
} else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0) {
   date.setText("Tanggal 2 sama 1");
} else {
   btn_lunch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lunch_inactive);
   btn_dinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dinner_inactive);
   date.setText("Tanggal 1 lebih besar dari tanggal 2");
}
```

but it give me error when trying to change button with **setBackgroundResource** the error says...

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference

the code just error when trying to change button or set enabled the button.. the code normally can use when trying to use textview...
where is my mistake?

this is my complete class..

```
public class ProductBuyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int user_id;
    public String token = "",difday,diff,val;
    static TextView date;
    ImageView imgbg;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public Button btn_lunch,btn_dinner;
    Context context;
    public final GlobalVar globalvar = (GlobalVar)GlobalVar.getAppContex();
    public String final_date;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_buy_layout);
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.shared), MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String userdata = shared.getString("user_data", "");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        try {
            JSONObject userobject = new JSONObject(userdata);
            user_id = userobject.getInt("id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AssetManager am = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets();


        TextView login_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

        TextView product_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_name);

        product_name.setText(globalvar.getProductName());
        TextView product_portion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_portion);

        product_portion.setText(String.valueOf(globalvar.getQty())+" Portion");

        imgbg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebg);
        String detailimg = extras.getString("ImageURL");

        int total_price = 0;
        total_price = Integer.valueOf(globalvar.getProductPrice()) * globalvar.getQty();

        if(globalvar.getFrom().equals("main")){
            total_price = Integer.valueOf(globalvar.getProductPrice()) * globalvar.getQty();
        }else{
            total_price = Integer.valueOf(globalvar.getProductPrice()) * globalvar.getQty();
        }

        TextView product_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        product_price.setTypeface(font);
        product_price.setText(HelperClass.price(String.valueOf(total_price)));
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt.setTypeface(font4);
        btn_lunch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lunch);
        btn_dinner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dinner);
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setTypeface(font);
        Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setTypeface(font);

        date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setTypeface(font);
        request_validation();
        // Get current date by calender


        // Button listener to show date picker dialog


            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Show current date

            StringBuilder current_date = new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                    .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                    .append(year).append(" ");

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            Date mydate = null;
            try{
                mydate = dateFormat.parse(current_date.toString());
            }catch(ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat custome_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM' 'dd','yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String final_date = custome_date.format(mydate);
            globalvar.setDate(final_date);
            date.setText(final_date);


        // Button listener to show date picker dialog

        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                show_date_picker();

            }

        });

        ImageView back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                go_back();
            }
        });

        globalvar.setOrderTime(0);


    }

    public void setdate(){
        GlobalVar globalvar = (GlobalVar)GlobalVar.getAppContex();
        difday = globalvar.get_diffday();
        int adddate=0;
        String logadd = String.valueOf(adddate);

        Log.e("Logadd",logadd);
        if(difday.equals("2")){
            adddate = 2;
            logadd = String.valueOf(adddate);
            Log.e("Logadd2",logadd);
        }else {
            adddate = 1;
            logadd = String.valueOf(adddate);
            Log.e("Logadd1",logadd);
        }
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Show current date

        StringBuilder current_date = new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day+adddate).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" ");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date mydate = null;
        try{
            mydate = dateFormat.parse(current_date.toString());
        }catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat custome_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM' 'dd','yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String final_date = custome_date.format(mydate);
        globalvar.setDate(final_date);
        date.setText(final_date);

    }

    public void go_checkout(View v){

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        ShoppingCartList cartlist = new ShoppingCartList();
        cartlist.setProductId(globalvar.getProductId());
        cartlist.setProductName(globalvar.getProductName());
        cartlist.setProductPrice(globalvar.getProductPrice());
        cartlist.setImage(globalvar.getImage());
        cartlist.setQty(globalvar.getQty());
        cartlist.setDate(globalvar.getDate());
        cartlist.setOrderTime(globalvar.getOrderTime());
        cartlist.setProductSellingPrice(globalvar.getProductSellingPrice());
        cartlist.setuserID(user_id);
        //db.addCart(cartlist);
        if(globalvar.getFrom().equals("main")){
            if(db.Cart_Exists(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(), user_id)){
                ShoppingCartList cart_detail = db.getCart(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(), user_id);
            }

//        if(db.Cart_Exists(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate())){
//
//            ShoppingCartList cart_detail = db.getCart(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate());
//
//            cart_detail.setQty(cart_detail.getQty() + globalvar.getQty());
//
//            db.updateChart(cart_detail);

        }else{
            db.addCart(cartlist);
        }

        if(globalvar.getFrom().equals("main")){
            if(db.Cart_Exists(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id)){

                ShoppingCartList cart_detail = db.getCart(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id);

                cart_detail.setQty(cart_detail.getQty() + globalvar.getQty());

                db.updateChart(cart_detail);

            }else{
                db.addCart(cartlist);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(db.Cart_ExistsPaket(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id)){

                ShoppingCartList cart_detail = db.getCartPaket(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id);

                cart_detail.setQty(cart_detail.getQty() + globalvar.getQty());

                db.updateChartPaket(cart_detail);

            }else{
                db.addCartPaket(cartlist);
            }
        }

        db.close();

        Toast.makeText(ProductBuyActivity.this, "Added To Shopping Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        if(globalvar.getFrom().equals("main")){
            this.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShoppingCartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
//            this.finish();
//            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderPacketActivity.class);
//            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void go_addchart(View v){

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        ShoppingCartList cartlist = new ShoppingCartList();
        cartlist.setProductId(globalvar.getProductId());
        cartlist.setProductName(globalvar.getProductName());
        cartlist.setProductPrice(globalvar.getProductPrice());
        cartlist.setImage(globalvar.getImage());
        cartlist.setQty(globalvar.getQty());
        cartlist.setDate(globalvar.getDate());
        cartlist.setOrderTime(globalvar.getOrderTime());
        cartlist.setProductSellingPrice(globalvar.getProductSellingPrice());
        cartlist.setuserID(user_id);
        if(globalvar.getFrom().equals("main")){


            if(db.Cart_Exists(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id)){

                ShoppingCartList cart_detail = db.getCart(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id);

                cart_detail.setQty(cart_detail.getQty() + globalvar.getQty());

                db.updateChart(cart_detail);

            }else{
                db.addCart(cartlist);
            }
        }else{
            if(db.Cart_ExistsPaket(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id)){

                ShoppingCartList cart_detail = db.getCartPaket(globalvar.getProductId(), globalvar.getOrderTime(), globalvar.getDate(),user_id);

                cart_detail.setQty(cart_detail.getQty() + globalvar.getQty());

                db.updateChartPaket(cart_detail);

            }else{
                db.addCartPaket(cartlist);
            }
        }

        db.close();

        Toast.makeText(ProductBuyActivity.this, "Added To Shopping Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(globalvar.getFrom().equals("main")){

            this.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void selectlunch(View v){


        btn_lunch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lunch_active);


        btn_dinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dinner_inactive);

        globalvar.setOrderTime(0);

    }

    public void selectdinner(View v){


        btn_lunch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lunch_inactive);


        btn_dinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dinner_active);

        globalvar.setOrderTime(1);

    }

    private void show_date_picker(){
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            GlobalVar globalvar = (GlobalVar)GlobalVar.getAppContex();
            String difdays = globalvar.get_diffday();
            int adddate=0;
            String logadd = String.valueOf(adddate);
            Log.e("Logadd",logadd);
            if(difdays.equals("2")){
                adddate = 2;
                logadd = String.valueOf(adddate);
                Log.e("Logadd2",logadd);
            }else {
                adddate = 1;
                logadd = String.valueOf(adddate);
                Log.e("Logadd1",logadd);
            }
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+adddate;

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, this, year, month, day+adddate);

            //dpd.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
            dpd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 );
            dpd.setTitle("Select Day"); // Uncomment this line to activate it

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return dpd;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Log.d("Date", "Year=" + year + " Month=" + (month + 1) + " day=" + dayOfMonth);

        }
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            GlobalVar globalvar = (GlobalVar)GlobalVar.getAppContex();

            StringBuilder current_date = new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                    .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                    .append(year).append(" ");

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            Date mydate = null;
            try{
                mydate = dateFormat.parse(current_date.toString());
            }catch(ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            SimpleDateFormat custome_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String final_date = custome_date.format(mydate);

            globalvar.setDate(final_date);
            date.setText(final_date);
            ProductBuyActivity product = new ProductBuyActivity();
            product.compareDate(final_date);
//            product.differenDate(final_date,"0");
        }


    }
    public void enabled_button(){
        btn_lunch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lunch_active);
        btn_lunch.setEnabled(true);
        btn_dinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dinner_active);
        btn_dinner.setEnabled(true);
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "date2 is Greater than my date1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void disabled_button(){
        btn_lunch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lunch_inactive);
        btn_lunch.setEnabled(false);
        btn_dinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dinner_inactive);
        btn_dinner.setEnabled(false);
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "date2 is Greater than my date1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void compareDate(String final_date) {
        try{
            Context context;
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy");

            Date date1 = formatter.parse(final_date.toString());
            Log.e("Taggal Selected:",date1.toString());

            String str2 = "March 10, 2017";
            Date date2 = formatter.parse(str2);

            if (date1.compareTo(date2)<0)
            {
                System.out.print("Date2 is Greater than mydate1");
                date.setText("Tanggal 2 lebih besar dari tanggal 1");
////                btn_lunch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lunch_inactive);
//                btn_lunch.setEnabled(false);
////                btn_dinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dinner_inactive);
//                btn_dinner.setEnabled(false);
                    enabled_button();
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "date2 is Greater than my date1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Same Date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.print("Same Date");
                date.setText("Tanggal 2 sama 1");
            }
            else{
//                disabled_button();

                System.out.print("Date1 is Greater than mydate2");
                date.setText("Tanggal 1 lebih besar dari tanggal 2");
            }

        }catch (ParseException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void request_token() {


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.API) + "oauth/token",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.i("respon token", response);

                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //String token = "";

                        try {

                            JSONObject return_val = new JSONObject(response);
                            token = return_val.getString("access_token");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.shared), MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("token", token);
                        editor.commit();

                        request_validation();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProductBuyActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("grant_type", getResources().getString(R.string.grant_type));
                map.put("username", getResources().getString(R.string.username));
                map.put("password", getResources().getString(R.string.password));
                map.put("client_id", getResources().getString(R.string.client_id));
                map.put("client_secret", getResources().getString(R.string.client_secret));
                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void go_back(){
        this.finish();
    }
    private void showPDialog() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductBuyActivity.this, R.style.MyTheme);
        //pDialog.setTitle("Loading... Please Wait");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_Material_ProgressBar_Large);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        go_back();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you initialize `btn_lunch` and `btn_dinner`?

Comment: @cipley yes i have initialize the button in onCreate...

Comment: NPE occurs when you tried to use uninitialized object. Can you post your `onCreate` method?

Comment: btn_lunch/btn_dinner either or both are null..thats why its throwing NPE.. means you did not initialize buttons properly. pls post OnCreate().

Comment: @cipley yes i have edited my question and put onCreate in there..

Comment: @user392117 i have post my OnCreate()

Comment: Ok we're getting there, now can you please post your `product_buy_layout` XML?

Comment: @cipley done.. i've edited the question and post product_buy..  in this class i've already use the button successfully but when i trying to use it in compareDate it give me error

Comment: what is the scope of your buttons (private/public)? And where does `compareDate` resides? Is it in the same activity?

Comment: @cipley i don't know about scope. but i initialize the button just like usual.
Button btn_lunch, btn_dinner;
and compareDate in same activity but in different method..

Comment: @cipley actually i want to change the resourcesbackground of the button and disabled it when user do a change on datepicker ...

Comment: Ok now can you please post your complete `Activity` code?

Comment: @cipley done.. but i cut some code cause there is limit of post question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProductBuyActivity product = new ProductBuyActivity();
```

You instantiate your activity without any intent. Thus, `onCreate` would **not** be called.

This makes your `compareDate` method getting confused by trying to use `product`'s `btn_lunch` and `btn_dinner`, which will be uninitialized - therefore, is `null`

`compareDate()` is a public method, <del>you can simply call `compareDate(final_date);`</del> you can try to use

```
ProductBuyActivity.this.compareDate(final_date);
```

There is no need to instantiate a new Activity Project.

**EDIT:**

If fully refactoring your code is not an option, then you need to have a Listener callback for your `DatePickerDialog`.

Leave your `DatePickerDialog` static.

**Do not** implement `OnDateSetListener` interface on your fragment.
Instead, implement it on your **Activity**

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener

public class ProductBuyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
```

Move your `onDataSet` to Activity, overriding the Interface

```
public class ProductBuyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{


    .....


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        GlobalVar globalvar = (GlobalVar)GlobalVar.getAppContex();

        StringBuilder current_date = new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" ");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date mydate = null;
        try{
            mydate = dateFormat.parse(current_date.toString());
        }catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        SimpleDateFormat custome_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String final_date = custome_date.format(mydate);

        globalvar.setDate(final_date);
        date.setText(final_date);
        //ProductBuyActivity product = new ProductBuyActivity();
        //product.compareDate(final_date);
        compareDate(final_date);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**:

Change your `DatePickerDialog` instantiation:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, (ProductBuyActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day+adddate);
```

Comment: it give me error if i use ProductBuyActivity.this.compareDate(final_date);

cannot be referenced from static context..

Comment: Because your `DatePickerFragment` is declared as static. either you make `compareDate` also static or declare `DatePickerFragment` as non static

Comment: On second thought, your `DatePickerFragment` should not be declared as static. You did instantiate it at `show_date_picker`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `static` from your Fragment declaration?

Comment: yes i have..
but it give another error..
"this fragment inner class should be static.."

Comment: hai ... i  follow your edited answer and i got one error in here

DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, this, year, month, day+adddate);
 the expected parameter listener is OnDateSetListener but "this" in datepickerdialog is datepickerfragment.
sorry.. could you help me again..

Answer (score 0):

Use below to get different and achieve your goal..

```
public static void differenDate(String startDate, String endDate) {
    Log.d("S D", "--->   S D = " + startDate);
    Log.d("E D", "--->   E D = " + endDate);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.sss");
    Date sDate = null;
    Date eDate = null;
    try {
        sDate = format.parse(startDate);
        eDate = format.parse(endDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // final int MILLI_TO_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;
    // int diff = (int) ( (eDate.getTime() - sDate.getTime()) / MILLI_TO_HOUR );
    System.out.println("DIFF = " + (eDate.getTime() - sDate.getTime()));

    int calcDiff = (int) (eDate.getTime() - sDate.getTime());

}
```

Comment: what do you mean? it will result int value right ? so how can i do for setBackgroundResource if the value like this "172800000"?

Comment: cause if i use compareDate it will give value ==0, <1 or >1

Comment: Please do your self it's just simple logic to set your own drawable.. according to your goal...